# Get properties value from dbId or externalid - Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I have dbId and externalId in forge viewer. I want to get some value of properties object from this dbId and externalId. For example: Perimeter, Area, Volume, ...

What is the syntax to do that?

[image: View Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the DBID for the element which you can obtain with a viewer call to the selection of the object. `viewer.getSelection()` will give you that DBID that we will use later.

You can use the method `getProperties(dbid, callback)` For example something like this.

```
var myDbid = viewer.getSelection();
viewer.getProperties(myDbid, function(e){
      console.log('Entire object response ',e);
      console.log('Properties ',e.properties)
});
```

This should give you the information of the category you are looking for.